# C++ Incrementing a pointer into unknown memory territory

Tags: c++, memory, pointers

I have a query about the behavior of C/C++ dealing with blindly incrementing a pointer.

So, I have a pointer to an int as a parameter to a function

`func(int* thePointer) {...`

and I have a loop inside that function

```
while(*thePointer) {
    ++thePointer;
}
```

I understand that as long as there are `int`'s in the memory beyond this pointer the loop will continue, but what if the memory belongs to part of another memory type? Say you increment into the first 4 bytes of a `double`. Will the int still have a value/will the loop continue in this case?

Disclaimer: I know this is very most likely bad practice. This is a purely academic question.

Comment: Demons will fly out your nose.

Comment: blindly incrementing a pointer is a quite beyond very most likely bad practice ... say that out loud then read this twice: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/ and you'll be feeling better by morning.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In memory there is no such thing as a **int** or a **double**. Memory is just memory: placeholder for bytes.

So, if you keep incrementing a pointer to **int**, you will point to the next four bytes in memory and that's it. If you attempt to use that portion of the memory through the pointer to integer, you will probably treat its content as if it were an **int**.

Eventually, you will point to a region of the memory not being assigned to your process and your program will exit with a **SEGMENTATION FAULT**.

Comment: +1 for covering some core issues concisely.  FWIW to Dfowj, accessing memory "as if" it contains ints and checking against 0 simply checks no bits are set in that memory.  A float or double with no bits sets just happens to have a value of +0.0 too (in the industry-standard IEEE representation); there's a distinct representation for the mysterious "-0.0" - such things are normally beneath visibility in C++.

Answer (score 4):

ISO 14882, section 5.7:

> $4 For the purposes of these operators, a
>   pointer to a nonarray object behaves
>   the same as a pointer to the first
>   element of an array of length one with
>   the type of the object as its element
>   type.
>
> $5 When an expression that has
>   integral type is added to or
>   subtracted from a pointer, the result
>   has the type of the pointer operand.
>   If the pointer operand points to an
>   element of an array object, and the
>   array is large enough, the result
>   points to an element offset from the
>   original element such that the
>   difference of the subscripts of the
>   resulting and original array elements
>   equals the integral expression. In
>   other words, if the expression P
>   points to the ith element of an array
>   object, the expressions (P)+N
>   (equivalently, N+(P)) and (P)N (where
>   N has the value n) point to,
>   respectively, the i+nth and i– nth
>   elements of the array object, provided
>   they exist. Moreover, if the
>   expression P points to the last
>   element of an array object, the
>   expression (P)+1 points one past the
>   last element of the array object, and
>   if the expression Q points one past
>   the last element of an array object,
>   the expression (Q)1 points to the last
>   element of the array object. If both
>   the pointer operand and the result
>   point to elements of the same array
>   object, or one past the last element
>   of the array object, the evaluation
>   shall not produce an overflow;
>   otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

Comment: When the specification says "the evaluation shall not produce an overflow; otherwise, the behavior is undefined".  Does the "evaluation" means evaluation of the dereferencing the pointer pointing to 1 past the last element?  It sounds to me that it is okay to have a pointer to point to anywhere (numerically) as long as dereference doesn't happen on that pointer. There is no harm or error per standard.  Am I correct?

Comment: Strangely, I think not. Evaluation does not mean dereferencing, it means evaluation of the pointer expression. You cannot dereference one past the last element, but you can compare the pointer value. This is so that the notion of `end` works. Why not have a pointer to `anywhere` - a good question. Suppose you're on a 32-bit machine, and just keep incrementing, you'll eventually get an overflow. So the standard is defining what had better work without getting into machine dependent stuff. I can also see that a debugging implementation might choose to trap cases where pointers are invalid.

Comment: Thanks for your input Keith. I was hoping to keep increasing the pointer to a buffer (e.g. for reading data from a TCP socket) without worrying the boundary given that my application won't actually read (i.e. deference the pointer) anything out of boundary.

Answer (score 2):

> but what if the memory belongs to part of another memory type? Say you increment into the first 4 bytes of a double. Will the int still have a value/will the loop continue in this case?

The compiler doesn't care what type of memory is there.  You can increment into any type of memory you choose, and it will be fine.

It will only have a problem when you try to *access* that memory location.  If you try to set a value at the pointer location, and it's not memory allocated to your process, it will crash.

As long as the memory at the location belongs to you (ie: your program allocated it), you'll be able to set it.  That being said, if the memory location wasn't something you were treating as an integer value, you'll most likely corrupt the state of some other object, which will eventually lead to bad things happening.

Comment: -1: Not true. Incrementing past the end of an object (and accessing the memory read/write) results in UB. If the object is a the address of an int then any increment is beyond. If the address points into an array then moving beyond the end of the array.

Comment: Actually pointing (not accessing) at the next element beyond an array is valid. In fact, this is exactly what the `end()` iterator for a `vector<>` is doing.

Comment: Keith's statement rings a bell - valid to go one past the end of an array, but generally incrementing a pointer's not guaranteed to be safe: presumably there are (or were) memory models out there where certain CPU's registers aren't capable of incrementing outside certain bounds, perhaps due to weird segmentation handling rules etc..  @Reed: "memory belongs to you...able to set it" isn't true - memory can be mapped read-only.  And the idea of "types of memory" should be debunked up front... :-).

Answer (score 1):

I join everybody. Thinking of doing that, even with academic purposes, is opening the door for the devil. The pointer will advance the size of int each time, no matter what is in memory. When accessing that you will get garbage.

Answer (score 1):

Moving a pointer is dangerous if you access the memory (read or write).

Moving a pointer past the end of the current object and de-referencing the object is undefined behavior.

Single Object:

```
int  x;
int* xp = &x;

xp++; // Now pointing past the object.
int  y  = *xp; // Undefined behavior.
```

Array:

```
int  x[10];
int  xp = x;

while(*xp)
{   ++xp;  // Works fine the first 9 times.
}          // After that it is UB to access the memory pointed at by xp
```

Note: on looping

```
while(*xp)  // This continues while the memory pointed at
            // is not zero. As soon as a zero is found in memory
            // the loop exits.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you keep incrementing, eventually you will get a SIGSEGV or the Windows Moral Equivalent. However, before you get there, you are likely to take a Cooke's Tour of whatever else is lying about in VM. Other variables, disused sandwich wrappers, whatever.

Loops like this are not just 'bad practice', they are a major source of exploits.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have above has nothing to do with how many `int`s there are in memory. Your code goes until is finds the equivalent of an integer set to zero.

Yes, this is very bad practice. The results are undefined. You are more than likely to encounter memory that is not part of the expected array. And you have a high chance that you go into memory that cause a processor fault.